# Specifying Time Periods in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

In Python (and Pandas), we have excellent data structures to deal with dates and times. We have `datetime` which represents the (date and) time, and `timedelta` which represents the time difference.

Now, I have a list of variables whose values are different during different times. Is there an efficient data structure for that? Is there a data-structure for specifying "periods"?

### My Implementation

Currently, I am doing this in the following manner:

- I define a data-structure containing information on the value of the variables in a tuple-format. The variables are stored as keys of a dictionary, with their values (in tuple format) specifying value according to datetime period. So, e.g.,  `("23-05-1990", "12-01-2000", 45)` means that the value of the variable is `45` from `23-05-1990` to `12-01-2000`. If any of the starting or ending datetime string is empty, it is understood that there is no restriction on that end. So, e.g., `("12-01-2010", "", 13)` would mean that the value is `13` from `12-01-2010` to forever in future.
- A function is then defined in which you give the variable name and a given timestamp. It uses this data-structure to evaluate the value of that variable for the given timestamp.

```py
mydict = {
  "a" : (
            ("23-05-1990", "12-01-2000", 45),
            ("12-01-2000", "12-01-2010", 78),
            ("12-01-2010", "", 123),
        ),
  "b" : (
            ("", "12-01-2000", 145),
            ("14-01-2001", "12-01-2010", 781),
            ("2-01-2012", "", 13),
        )
}
```

Now, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this, or something inbuilt into Python's (or Pandas') datetime libraries for the same.

Comment: You seem to be double-writing each cutoff date. Rather than doing that, would it not be possible to simply store a single date, and for each interval check if the requested time is between the current and the next interval? Maybe also make a dummy value for "beginning of time"

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Actually, in some cases, the cutoff date is not aligned for 2 periods. See the updated values in my question for `"b"` key.

Comment: Use a datetime column as your index and every possible timestamp where there is an event, have a row. The values can just be forward filled from the event that they started on to the event they stop on.